# unable to read makefile using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile

I am trying to read the contents of the Makefile using python.

### Makefile

```
# Dev Makefile

SHELL := /bin/bash
platform_ns ?= abc
app_namespace ?= xyz

wftmpl = wftmpl.yaml
wftmpl_name ?= abc.yaml
service_account ?= dev_account
br_local_port = 8000
tr_local_port = 8001
storage_root_path ?= some_location
```

I used the following code to read the file in python file expocting all the files in the same directory.

### python_script.py

```
with open("Makefile", "r") as file:
    while (line := file.readline().rstrip()):
        print(line)
```

### Expected output

```
# Dev Makefile

SHELL := /bin/bash
platform_ns ?= abc
app_namespace ?= xyz

wftmpl = wftmpl.yaml
wftmpl_name ?= abc.yaml
service_account ?= dev_account
br_local_port = 8000
tr_local_port = 8001
storage_root_path ?= some_location
```

### Current output

`# Dev Makefile`

I need to print all the content of the Makefile using python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `while` condition is the line after calling `rstrip()`. If the line is blank, this will be an empty string, and this is falsey, so the loop ends.

You should test the line *before* stripping it.

```
while (line := file.readline()):
    print(line.rstrip())
```

or more simply:

```
for line in file:
    print(line.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
with open("Makefile", "r") as file:
    for line in file.read().splitlines():
        print(line)
```

Comment: Or simply: `for line in file:`